# Web.config file error: Unable to access SQL database with Azure mobile services

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services

I'm working with a Xamarin.iOS app.I imported a database from one subscription to another in the Azure portal. I then opened up the Web Deploy.pubxml file and updated the `Destination Path` to point to the new server and new database.

I haven't updated anything in the web.config file. When I try to log into my app, I get the following error in the logs:

```
IIS Detailed Error - 500.0 - Internal Server Error

IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly

The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL
```

The **connectionString** is still pointing to the old data in the web.config file. Does this need to change? If yes, where do I retrieve the new connectionString from?

Comment: Make sure the firewall for the SQL server is appropriately set.  Also, I would redeploy the backend from your code - this should correct any lingering permissions issues.

Comment: Hi @Adrian Hall, Thanks for your response. I ensured that the server was set up correctly and all but I kept getting the error. After a little more debugging, I realized that there were some missing assemblies being referenced in the web.config file, hence, the error. I'm gonna post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more debugging, I realized that there were some missing assemblies being referenced in the web.config file. The package was missing from the project, yet it was still being referenced in the web.config file.

This library was missing:

```
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

So I added the System.Web.Mvc library to the project and that updated the web.config file.